# Ruby adding values to output after executing loop

Tags: ruby

I have the following code:

```
$excel = WIN32OLE.new('Excel.Application')
$excel.visible = true

puts 'Filepath?'
$filepath = $stdin.gets.chomp
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($filepath)
puts $workbook

puts 'Sheet?' 
$worksheet = $workbook.Worksheets
$count = $worksheet.Count
for i in 1..$count do 
    $array = $workbook.Worksheets(i).Name
    puts i.to_s + "." + " " + $array
end
```

It's a part of a Ruby script that I'm using to manage and edit Excel files. I went with 'win32ole' because the files I'm interacting with are fairly large and I find that it's much faster than something like 'roo'. So my code does what I need it to do and that's go out and get all the sheet names within a specified spreadsheet. However for some reason it adds these values before and after my results:

```
#<WIN32OLE:0x291a878>
Sheet?"
1. Sheet1
2. Sheet2
3. Sheet3
1..3
```

I have no idea where `#<WIN32OLE:0x291a878>` or `1..3` are coming from but any help to trim these out would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: The first line comes from `puts $workbook`. As for the `1..3`, nothing in the code you provided prints that.

Answer (score 1):

The first line `#<WIN32OLE:0x291a878>` is the output of `puts $workbook`. It is the inspection string of a `WIN32OLE` instance.

You probably ran this in a REPL, and `1..3` is the return value of the last expression `for i in 1..$count do ... end`, which is printed by the REPL.